# ¿me pueden echar una mano para a arreglar este codigo de python?

Tags: python, array

buenas tengo este codigo pero no se en que me he equivocado y aparte   me piden crear un menu pero lo que no doy hacer es guardar varios usuariops y contraseña

```
namUser="Danimt"
passord="Qdani120"


print("Menú: ")
print("   1. Crear nuevo usuario")
print("   2. Iniciar sesión")
print("   3. Salir")
namUser= int(input("Ingrese una opción:"))


if namUser>3:
    print("Error. Ingrese opción 1, 2 o 3.")
```

hasta este punto estoy bien pero en lo siguiente me enrede

```
if namUser == 1:
    newName = input("Ingrese nuevo nombre de usuario. Mínimo 5 carácteres(letras):")
    if newName.isalpha():
        if len(newName)<5:
            print("Error. Ingrese mínimo 5 carácteres")
       

        else:
            print("Error. Ingrese solo letras(A a P p E e)")
```

no se como arreglar esta parte y me toca agrecar la de la contraseña

```
if namUser == 2:
   name=input("Ingrese su nombre de usuario:")
   
   if name == namUser:
       print("Ingrese contraseña:")

   else:
       print("Error. Éste usuario no está registrado.")


if namUser ==3:
 print("Programa cerrado.")
```

Comment: Buen día, no es muy claro cual es el problema. En donde dices, "En lo siguiente me enredé", ¿Cuál es el problema? o ¿Qué esperarías que sucediera? y ¿Cuál es el problema con la contraseña?

Comment: ok  es al momento de copilar el if ==1: coloco el nombre como lo pedi  que sea menor que 5 pero se cumpe es el if  que me imprime "error"

Comment: entoces a ese ciclo quiero agregarle lo de la contraseña

Comment: es peraria que en el  primer ciclo con las condiciones que colo que se me almacena el uasuari y la contraseña pero como dije no  doy a anexar la parte de la contraseña del usuario

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas sobre escribiendo el valor de "la constate" `namUser = "Danimt"`, ahi puedes a) cambiar el nombre de esa constante y actualizar la linea donde comparas con el usuario ingresado, o b) usar otra variable para almacenar la opción que selecciona el usuario del menú, yo iría por la opción 2.

Algo como lo siguiente:

```py
namUser="Danimt"
passord="Qdani120"


print("Menú: ")
print("   1. Crear nuevo usuario")
print("   2. Iniciar sesión")
print("   3. Salir")

# Aquí en lugar de namUser, podemos decir option, y cambiar 
# la demás referencia a esta variable
option = int(input("Ingrese una opción:"))


if option == 1:
    # Código para registrar usuario
else if option == 2:
    # Código para ingresar con usuario y contraseña
else if option == 3:
    # Código para terminar programa
else:
    print("Error. Ingrese opción 1, 2 o 3.")
```

Y para lo de la contraseña, se podría aplicar lo mismo que se esta utilizando para solicitar y comparar el nombre de usuario.

```py
# Código para ingresar con usuario y contraseña
name = input("Ingrese su nombre de usuario:")
p = input("Ingrese su contraseña:")

if name == namUser and p == passord:
   print("Bienvenido")
else:
   print("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos")
```

Por cierto revisa tus variables y que estas sean los mas explicitas posible, creo que tienes un typo para password y para nameUser, en lugar de nameUser es más gramaticalmente correcto username.